# I want to align a image in using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I am new to jQuery How to  align a image

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function bannerBackstretch() { 
        $("#banner").backstretch("{% media 'bg-photography.jpg'  %}").css('top', '-32px');
    }
    bannerBackstretch();
    $(document).on("click", ".domainchecker .nav-tabs li",bannerBackstretch);
</script>
```

Comment: did your banner position is absolute?

Comment: can you provide more info??